# Chrome for Mobile stops my video if switched to background

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, video, mobile-chrome

I provide a mobile site on which users are able to watch videos (embedded via HTML5 video). My users request that the video should continue to play if they switch to another app or lock the screen to save battery. It would be okay, if they have to "Phone-OS-level-ACK" this background play behavior before switching to another app.

Is there something I can do on my mobile page to support this kind of behavior? I've [read that Chrome >= 54 should have support to do this](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/09/16/chrome-54-background-html5-video-play-on-android/), but my videos still stop immediately after switching to another app. What kind of sorcery is required to support that feature for my users?

Comment: The youtube account your using should have youtubered purchased to allow background video play.

Comment: I'm not talking about YouTube videos, so I guess your comment does not really help.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the Beta release of Chrome to access this functionality first - if so then they linked article implies the video will indeed stop but you can start it again via notifications. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: @Mick: Actually, the "beta" they are talking about in the article is already officially released by now (Chrome 54). And yes, I don't see the notification thingy with my Chrome on Android.

Comment: It will pop in your notification bar and you can play from there. Just make sure your Google Chome has permission to post notifications.

Answer (score 7):

It will pop in your notification bar and you can play from there. Just make sure your Google Chome has permission to post notifications